# How to upload user data to a database and retrieve the data when needed (I'm trying to make a discord RPG Bot)

Tags: java, database, discord-jda

I am making an RPG Discord Bot using JDA, but I got stuck when trying to make a leveling system where people can level up by typing a certain command multiple times (similar to MEE6 chat level).

I can make a leveling system, but I just don't know how to save users' levels when the bot goes offline for an update. Some help would be appreciated.

I have searched for many tutorials online, and I also have read through Google's startup guide for databases but I still don't understand how to make everything work.

Comment: this may help https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Thanks! I will read it right now!!